# BSOD after Windows 10 Update

Tags: windows-10, bsod

I got the Blue Screen of Death after downloading an update. I've been trying to do a system restore but the C: option is grayed out and says:

> You must enable system protection on this drive.

Recently I’ve opened the Command Prompt and it takes me to:

`X:\windows\system32>`

In which I’ve entered `Rstrui.exe/offline:C:\windows=active`

From there I can only select the E: (System) to do the system restore, but it ends in it being unsuccessful, stating:

> System Restore failed while restoring the registry from the restore point. An unspecified error occurred during System Restore. (0x80070002)

I’m not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Open Control Panel, Security and Maintenance, Pull down Maintenance. What are the "Stopped Working" errors?  Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run dism.exe /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth followed by SFC /SCANNOW.   Restart and test

Comment: I am unable to get to the desktop so I can’t open the control panel. I tried the “dism.exe...” command and it returned “Error: 87” along with saying the command is unknown. Doing the scan results in “Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation.”

Comment: For a proper repair at this point (Windows 10 is not running), you need to back up all your data and reinstall Windows from the Windows 10 ISO

Comment: When I select the option to reset the PC, it says that there was a problem and no changes were made. It does this for when I both keep or remove the files

Comment: Yes. That is why I am saying that you need to back up the data and reinstall Windows. Your above comment confirms this. .

Comment: I see what you mean. When I bought this computer it already came with Windows installed. How could I obtain a copy of Windows on a flash drive for a decent price?

Comment: You can get the Windows 10 ISO from the Media Creation Link and make a USB key.  The Key is the only cost. There is no cost to Windows 10 since it has Windows 10. I adjusted my answer to include the MMC Link.

Answer (score 0):

> Summary from question:
>
> I tried the “dism.exe...” command ...  “Windows Resource Protection
> could not perform the requested operation.”

Windows is not running which means you cannot do a Repair Install.

So at this point, for a proper repair, back up all your data, favorites and email by starting in Safe Mode or Command to a USB Hard Drive connected to the system and reinstall Windows.

You can get the Windows 10 ISO for making a UBS Install Key from the Microsoft Media Creation Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

The re-install will correct deficiencies, and update drivers. Then you can install software slowly to make sure everything is running.